# Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS application loading is slow on my Dell Inspiron 640m

Tags: dell

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 on my Dell Inspiron which was running Windows 7. I have configured the dual boot option. Booting into Ubuntu is quite fast. However, I see that Ubuntu takes time to load my applications after I click on the icon in the launcher. I see this issue on most applications like Firefox, System Settings, GParted, etc.

Once the application is launched, the subsequent actions are fast. I don't have any issue in browsing, exploring the files, etc. It is just the initial load of the application that is taking time. When I did some research on this, the suggestion seems to be to install a lighter desktop environment. I like the default Ubuntu desktop environment. I have installed the Preload deamon service but have not noticed any improvements yet. Is my hardware not good enough for Ubuntu? Is there any other tweak that I can make to improve application loading?

My hardware configuration is

Dell Inspiron 640m
Processor  : Intel Core 2 Duo T5500 (1.66GHz, 2MB L2 Cache, 667 MHz FSB) 
Memory     : 2 GB DDR2 SDRAM at 533MHZ
Video Card : Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator 950

Answer (score 0):

A lighter desktop might help, although you should also check to make sure that OpenGL is using your graphics card capabilities.

open a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>), do `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils` then `glxinfo | grep renderer` - you do not want to see something about llvmpipes.

One solution would be to install preload, which causes often used applications to load into the cache shortly after booting.

`sudo apt-get install preload`

It does take 2 or three boot cycles to learn the applications that you often want loaded.

Comment: @tardistraveller I reread your question and noted that you already have preload installed.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I must have rebooted twice after installing preload. I am really hoping that it comes to my rescue soon. I will run the glxinfo command that you had suggested and post it in some time.

Comment: There's a [pretty good article about the effects of preload](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2013/05/using-preload-ubuntu-13-04/) that might shed some light on what you can expect.  I don't use it myself, because I have a separate issue with page cache, and don't find the small wait for the application to cause to much trouble for me.